# How do I combine rows in a matrix whose names partly contain same strings in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, aggregate

[image: image of my large matrix FedPapers_dtm_matrix]

So I have this large matrix. I want to combine all the Hamilton_fed_[number] and Madison_fed_[number] into one row with all the wordcounts added up. What are some of the ways to do it?

This is the code I used to generate the large matrix FedPapers_dtm_matrix

```
FedPapers_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(FedPapersCorpus,
                                control = list(
                                  stopwords = TRUE, 
                                  wordLengths=c(4, 10),
                                  removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                  removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                  tolower=TRUE,
                                  stemming = F, #stemming = F,
                                  stemWords=TRUE, #stemWords=TRUE,
                                  remove_separators = TRUE,
                                  stem=TRUE, #stem=TRUE,
                                  stopwords("english"),
                                  bounds = list(global = c(minTermFreq, maxTermFreq))
                                ))

FedPapers_dtm_matrix = as.matrix(FedPapers_dtm)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of grep and apply here, e.g. in order to get the sums of all rows containing "Hamilton_fed",

```
apply(df[grep(pattern = "Hamilton_fed", x = row.names(df)), ],
      MARGIN = 2, # i.e. column sum
      FUN = sum)
```

rbinding this to similarly summed rows should result in the data frame that you want.